# Is every finite dimension topological linear space locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

I know that every locally compact topological linear space X has finite dimension. I also know that A Hausdorff topological linear space is locally compact if and only if it is finite dimensional. But is every finite dimension topological linear space locally compact?

Comment: Yes if the field is the reals or $\Bbb C$.

Comment: What is your definition of "locally compact" for non-Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, even if the space is not hausdorff?

Comment: @PaulFrost, TVS is Locally compact if every point of $X$ has a base of compact neighborhoods.

Comment: A TVS is Hausdorff by definition.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, but my professor said that there are non-Hausdorff TVS.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma This depends on the "taste" of authors. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space.

Comment: Then it has to be Hausdorff as an extra necessary condition.

Comment: @PaulFrost in practice we will always have Hausdorff TVS’s

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Correct. And $X/\overline{\{0\}}$ is always a Hausdorff TVS, perhaps this helps.